# Make counsel-evil-marks select the candidate immediately, go to the mark in one click

Tags: counsel

I am using `counsel-evil-marks` in doom-emacs on Mac OS. When the mini buffer pops up, I still need to select the candidate and press enter.
How can I assign a key, so I switch immediately to the marked position, for example `C-a` to jump to the `a` mark?
[image]